# Discord py | Переотправка фото + текст, в другой канал

Tags: python, discord.py

Мне нужно что бы бот переотправлял фото и текст в эмбеде в отдельный канал, текст пере отправить легко, нужно просто прописать доп. аргумент и передать его с фото все гораздо сложнее я много чего перепробовал где только не лазил что только не пробовал, сейчас получается только так

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def trans(ctx, *, arg):
    channel = bot.get_channel(ну тут айди)
    embed = discord.Embed(description=f"{arg}", color=0xfcb51d)
    await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Искали везде за исключением [документации](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#how-do-i-use-a-local-image-file-for-an-embed-image)?

Использование: `transfer_` и в качестве аргумента передаём ссылку на сообщение

```
@commands.command()
async def transfer_(self, ctx: commands.Context, message_url: str):
    new_channel = 862001372114190387
    splited_url = message_url.split("/")
    guild_id = int(splited_url[4])
    channel_id = int(splited_url[5])
    message_id = int(splited_url[6])
    guild = self.bot.get_guild(guild_id)
    msg = await discord.utils.get(guild.text_channels, id=channel_id).fetch_message(message_id)
    attachments = msg.attachments
    if attachments:
        new_channel = discord.utils.get(guild.text_channels, id=new_channel)
        for attachment in attachments:
            await new_channel.send(attachment.url)
    else:
        await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention} ничего не найдено!")
```

Comment: Это я знаю, мне нужно ПЕРЕОТПРАВИТЬ ЧУЖУЮ, а не свою с пк

Comment: Исправил, теперь переотправляет все прикреплённые файлы, но можно сделать и проверку на изображения

Comment: Спасибо, но у меня все равно ничего не работает

Comment: discord: RAINGM#1941